# Notify does not work in the unlock method. Elements that are included in the wait, do not come out of waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm just starting to learn multithreading.

Notify does not work in the unlock method. Elements that are included in the wait, do not come out of waiting.

```
public class Tunnel {
    static AtomicInteger limit = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static boolean isOpen = false;
    void goIntoTunnel() throws InterruptedException {
        lock();
        int timeIntoTunnel = (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " go into the tunnel");
        Thread.sleep(timeIntoTunnel);
        unlock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " left the tunnel, time: " + timeIntoTunnel);
    }

    void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (limit.get() < 3) {
                limit.incrementAndGet();
            } else isOpen = true;
            while (isOpen) {
                wait();
            }
        }
    }

    void unlock() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            limit.getAndSet(limit.get()-1);
            isOpen = false;
                notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Simulation of the race. Cars enter the tunnel, and there cannot be more than 3 cars in the tunnel at the same time

Comment: Fixed bug with limitation. The Runnable interface is implemented in the Car class. The error still occurs.

Comment: `limit.getAndSet(limit.get()-1);` is a super bad pattern that introduces a possible race.  You are inside of a synchronized block whenever it is used so it doesn't matter in your case but `limit.decrementAndGet()` should be used with `AtomicInteger` instead.

Comment: Because you are inside of synchronized blocks whenever you are reading or adjusting the limit then it can be a simple int type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notify does not work in the unlock method. Elements that are included in the wait, do not come out of waiting.

Your code works fine on my machine.

The testing code:

```java
public class App {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    var numTasks = 10;
    var tunnel = new Tunnel();
    var startLatch = new CountDownLatch(numTasks);
    var threads = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numTasks).mapToObj(i -> {
      var t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
          startLatch.countDown();
          startLatch.await();
          tunnel.goIntoTunnel();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
      t.setName("Car" + i);
      return t;
    }).toList();
    threads.forEach(t -> t.start());
    for (var t: threads) {
      t.join();
    }
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Car1 go into the tunnel
Car3 go into the tunnel
Car2 go into the tunnel
Car4 go into the tunnel
Car1 left the tunnel, time: 327
Car4 left the tunnel, time: 2372
Car5 go into the tunnel
Car3 left the tunnel, time: 4174
Car6 go into the tunnel
Car2 left the tunnel, time: 4661
Car8 go into the tunnel
Car5 left the tunnel, time: 1995
Car7 go into the tunnel
Car8 left the tunnel, time: 2323
Car9 go into the tunnel
Car7 left the tunnel, time: 2794
Car10 go into the tunnel
Car6 left the tunnel, time: 3927
Car9 left the tunnel, time: 3367
Car10 left the tunnel, time: 4590
```

I don't see anything in the code of `Tunnel` that might prevent waiting threads from waking up:

1. every car-thread calls [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) in the end, this wakes up one waiting thread (if there are any)
2. the awoken thread also call [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()), this wakes up another waiting thread
3. ...

The only thing I can think of is if this `Tunnel` object is also used somewhere else in your code for waiting.
In this case [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) in `unlock()` might wake up that other waiting thread instead of one of the waiting car-threads.

P.S. There are some additional problems in your code:

1. `limit` is not incremented inside `lock()` when the thread is awoken. This might lead to 4 cars (3 threads that didn't wait + 1 awoken thread) in the tunnel simultaneously.
2. `Tunnel.isOpen` is `true` when the tunnel is closed, and is `false` when the tunnel is closed. That's counter-intuitive.
3. You can replace `AtomicInteger` by `int`, because in your code it's used only inside `synchronized` blocks. And code like `limit.getAndSet(limit.get()-1)` defeats the purpose of the `AtomicInteger`'s existence.

Comment: You completely rewrote the code.  I would have provided feedback on the code as posted and not provided another solution to what certainly is an academic problem.